# What do these lines of test do?

Tags: solidity, unittesting

Test file:

```
const {expect} = require("chai");
const {ethers} = require("hardhat");

describe("NFT Marketplace", function () {
    let NFTMarket;
    let nftMarket;
    let listingPrice;
    let contractOwner;
    let buyerAddress;
    let nftMarketAddress

    // returns a BigNumber representation of value, parsed with
    // digits (if it's a number) or from the unit specified (if it's a string)
    const auctionPrice = ethers.utils.parseUnits("100", "ether")

    // hooks that perform before each test case
    beforeEach(async () => { // get contract that we're targeting, so we can deploy or call the functions in that Contract
        NFTMarket = await ethers.getContractFactory("NFTMarketplace");

        // create a transaction to deploy the transaction and sends it to the network
        // using the contract Signer, and returning a Promise to resolve to a Contract
        nftMarket = await NFTMarket.deploy();

        // return a Promise which will resolve once the contract is deployed
        // or reject if there was an error during deployment
        await nftMarket.deployed();
        nftMarketAddress = nftMarket.address;
        [contractOwner, buyerAddress] = await ethers.getSigners(); // get public address of the user wallet
        listingPrice = await nftMarket.getListingPrice();
        listingPrice = listingPrice.toString();
    })

    // mint and list NFT
    const mintAndListNFT = async (tokenURI, auctionPrice) => {
        const transaction = await nftMarket.createToken(tokenURI, auctionPrice, {value: listingPrice});
        const receipt = await transaction.wait();
        const tokenId = receipt.events[0].args.tokenId;
        return tokenId;
    }
```

Contract file:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.9;
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";

contract NFTMarketplace is ERC721URIStorage {
    using Counters for Counters.Counter;
    Counters.Counter private _tokenIDs; // total number of items created
    Counters.Counter private _itemsSold; // total number of items sold

    uint256 listingPrice = 0.001 ether; // price to list NFT on marketplace
    address payable owner; // owner of the smart contract

    constructor() ERC721("Metaverse Tokens", "META") {
        owner == payable(msg.sender);
    }

    struct MarketItem {
        uint256 tokenId;
        address payable seller;
        address payable owner;
        uint256 price;
        bool sold;
    }

    mapping(uint256 => MarketItem) private idToMarketItem;

    event MarketItemCreated (uint256 indexed tokenId, address seller, address owner, uint256 price, bool sold);
        
    // return the listing price of the NFT
    function getListingPrice() public view returns(uint256) {
        return listingPrice;
    }

    // update the listing price
    function updatedListingPrice(uint _listingPrice) public payable{
        require(owner == msg.sender, "You are not the owner!");
        listingPrice = _listingPrice;
    }

    // mints a token and list it in the market
    function createToken(string memory tokenURI, uint256 price) public payable returns(uint) {
        _tokenIDs.increment();
        uint256 newTokenId = _tokenIDs.current();
        _mint(msg.sender, newTokenId);
        _setTokenURI(newTokenId, tokenURI);
        createMarketItem(newTokenId, price);
        return newTokenId;
    }
}
```

- What does `const transaction = await nftMarket.createToken(tokenURI, auctionPrice, {value: listingPrice});` do? Why is there a `{value: listingPrice}` here in this line?
- What does `const tokenId = receipt.events[0].args.tokenId;` do? Why is this line necessary here?

All help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `const transaction = await nftMarket.createToken(tokenURI, auctionPrice, {value: listingPrice});` simply calls the smart contract's `createToken` function and passes the 2 arguments `tokenURI` and `auctionPrice`. The `{value: listingPrice}` is just part of the transaction data. In this case, this `value` will be `msg.value` in the smart contract, use to pay for gas, buy/exchange tokens, etc. It's just the transaction's eth amount.

The `const tokenId = receipt.events[0].args.tokenId;` line simply gets the first event emitted by the `createToken` function in the smart contract, to then get the `tokenId` id parameter that it contains.

The first function that might emit an event that the `createToken` function calls, it's `_mint(msg.sender, newTokenId);`. If we take a look at the source code of that `_mint` function, we can see that it emits a `Transfer` event, like: `emit Transfer(address(0), to, tokenId);`

Check here:

https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol#L286

So, I assume that the `const tokenId = receipt.events[0].args.tokenId;` line is actually getting the `tokenId` that the `Transfer` function holds.

Edit...

To simplify what I mentioned about the "abstraction" that the `ethers.js` and/or `web3.js` do when you create a Javascript smart contract instance using the smart contract ABI, let's suppose they dynamically create a function like the following code:

```js
// Your wallet address
const FROM = '0xde0B295669a9FD93d5F28D9Ec85E40f4cb697BAe';

// The smart contract address
const TO = '0x11f4d0A3c12e86B4b5F39B213F7E19D048276DAe';

function createToken(tokenURI, auctionPrice, options) {

  //...
  // Let's suppose `tokenURI` has the value "tokenUri"
  tokenURI = "tokenURI";
  // Let's suppose `auctionPrice` has the value "50"
  auctionPrice = 50;
  //...

const data = web3.eth.abi.encodeFunctionCall({
  name: 'createToken',
  type: 'function',
  inputs: [{
      type: 'string',
      name: 'tokenURI'
  },{
      type: 'uint256',
      name: 'price'
  }]
}, [tokenURI, auctionPrice]);

// The above code returns `data`:

// // 0x72b3b620000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000320000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000008746f6b656e557269000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000;

  web3.eth.sendTransaction({
    from: '0xde0B295669a9FD93d5F28D9Ec85E40f4cb697BAe',
    to: '0x11f4d0A3c12e86B4b5F39B213F7E19D048276DAe',
    data: data, // Using the data encoded above
    value: options.value // Using the value set in `options` here.
  })
  .then(function(receipt){
    //...
  });

}
```

You just need to understand that whenever you create a Javascript smart contract instance with `ethers.js` or `web3.js` using your contract ABI, they dynamically create Javascript functions with the same parameters that your smart contract functions, with an extra parameter, the last parameter, that is used to specify more information about the transaction itself, like the `value`, `gasPrice`, etc. Parameters that are not defined as parameters of your real smart contract in Solidity, but are added to the transaction itself.

I hope you have understood.

Comment: But createToken() only takes two parameters "tokenURI" and "auctionPrice" in the function from the contract file, how can one put another argument "{value: listingPrice}" in the function when testing?

Comment: Because that call from Javascript is not your contract, obviously. It's just an abstraction. When you create a contract instance in Javascript, with its ABI, an extra parameter is expected at the end of the methods to indicate extra information or options. Javascript is dynamic and allows us to do things like this. When that javascript function is building your actual transaction, it uses that last parameter to setup the options, if available, but calls the actual smart contract methods with the expected 2 arguments.

Comment: Can you please explain what does “Because that call from Javascript is not your contract, obviously. It's just an abstraction” means?

Comment: Do you mind if you take a look at my other question as well? Thank you. https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/141170/confused-about-the-function-of-these-lines-of-test-code

Comment: Ok I have understood. Do you mind if you take a look at my other question too?